# Wrap iframe in div column

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I embedded youtube video using thumbnails by following this tutorial http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/.

html:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
  <div class="wrap-about">
    <div class="note">
      <div class="media-wrapper">
        <div class="youtube-player" data-id="l-XfztB0yss"></div>                                        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function() {
        var div, n,
            v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
        for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("data-id", v[n].dataset.id);
            div.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
            div.onclick = labnolIframe;
            v[n].appendChild(div);
        }
    });

function labnolThumb(id) {
    var thumb = '<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/mqdefault.jpg">',
        play = '<div class="play"></div>';
    return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play;
}

function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", this.dataset.id));
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}

</script>
```

The problem is how I want to wrap the iframe if the iframe is in javascript file where it supposedly to be in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to take the code to embed in youtube and set it in the div where you want to be wrapped. Youtube give you the chance to copy the code and personalize it with width nad height and more other.

Comment: embed youtube video by using iframe in div will make web page load very slow. The reason why I use thumbnail is to make sure the youtube video do not load during page load. But the video seems didnot wrap together with div.